# How to correct issue with creating Web API 2 OData Controller with Actions using EF code-gen template with VS 2013?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-templates

I have a couple of dev environments. In my older VS 2013 Ultimate, I can execute the Web API 2 OData Controller with Actions using Entity Framework template code to create classes.

The second is Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 2 RC. I can create other classes, however in trying to create the aforementioned, I get the following error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Error
>
> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Since I have installed other components, I reset all settings through Tools / Import Export Settings / Reset All Settings.

I even completely uninstalled/re-installed - same issue on all fronts.

In both environments the code is exactly the same, connection to the same db.

I have tried using the code templates folder from the working env in the newer env - no go.

I also tried removing Update 2 RC through Windows / Installed Updates, but the request is rejected, indicating VS requires this update to run.

Suggestions?

Comment: Having the same issues.. did you manage to resolve this? Thanks